# GEE filterBounds not working with S5P dataset

Tags: google-earth-engine

It seems to me `ee.ImageCollection.filterBounds` is not filtering properly a dataset from Sentinel-5P.
I get images which do not include the point, which is the same for `filterBounds` and `Map.setCenter`.

```
var dataset = 'COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2';
var band = 'tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density';
var begin_date = '2019-05-03'; var end_date = '2019-05-04';
var collection = ee.ImageCollection(dataset)
  .filterDate(begin_date, end_date);

// Number of S5P NO2 images in one day
print(collection.size()) // 14

var lat=18.232527; var long=-66.257565; // Puerto Rico
var point1 = ee.Geometry.Point([long, lat])
var collection_clean = collection.filterBounds(point1)

// Number of S5P NO2 images in one day
print(collection_clean.size()) // 14????? All images cross Puerto Rico????

// Take the first image and try to display it
var image = collection_clean.first().select(band);
var zoom=8;
Map.setCenter(long, lat, zoom);
var min_value = 0.00001; var max_value = 0.00003;
var visParams = {min: min_value,
  max: max_value,
  palette: ['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red']}

// Image can only be seen after zooming out 5 times
Map.addLayer(image, visParams, "NO2")
```

If you zoom out 5-6 times you can finally see the NO2 layer.

Comment: I think the protocol is to post your code in addition to the GEE link (please update your post). Can't really help with nothing to go on, but in my experience, 90% of these problems are user-error. However, I have run into weird cases (at high latitudes) that are similar to what you're describing here. Never found a solution for it.

Comment: Sorry for the link inconvenience, I have just copied the code.

Comment: @AlbertoJuliánRigau was my answer helpful? If so, please mark it as an answer using a grey / green checkmark to the left

Comment: I clicked the green check yesterday!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not `.filterBoudns()` what causes this problem. Images that S5p collects span from pole-to-pole and thus have a world-wide extent in GEE.

[image: s5p image footprint]

You can confirm it within GEE:

```
var s5p_no2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2");

var single_img = s5p_no2.first();

print(single_img.geometry()); // world-wide extent
```

So now, if you want to filter out images that do not have actual pixels within your area of interest (AOI) you can use [these solutions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/354398/34438). They are based not on filtering by image extent (bounding box) but on detecting pixels with data within AOI.

Comment: I have checked the solution you proposed, replacing ee.Reducer.allNonZero by ee.Reducer.anyNonZero, and at least I can filter the images. Later I might consider the solution with % of coverage. Thanks!